# VB.NET - Thread + invoke won't add controls to form

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

i´ve got a problem. i have multiple threads. each thread shall create a new tabpage. this tabpage shall contain a webbrowser element. the elements are not there yet. they shall be generated after the single threads (up to 20) have been started.

so, i´ve got everything right, i think. i´ve got threads, which call a delegate (as STA Thread) and after working the thread and adding the controls, everything is right, i dont get errors. But every time, the tabe page (including the browser) is "added", there will be no changes in the form. there is no error, but also nothing appears on the form.

what am i doing wrong?

this is the call

```
frmMain.navigateBrowser("http://example.com")
```

and then, in the "navigateBrowser" function i will generate some elements and then finally add the elements to the form

```
tcMain.TabPages.Add(tmpTab)
```

I´ve had it in a timer before and was working it over a class, which saves the "command" (you! navigate now!) in a global var. but this method was too slow and now i want to try it directly over invoke.

That´s it, hope you can help me :)

Comment: You can **only** create controls on the UI thread. You cannot use other threads for this.

Comment: As WebBrowser is implementing async process when you call Navigate(), you don't need to use multithreading. Simply create the tabs with the webBrowsers and call navigate() for each browser in sequence. Each browser will in parallel load the pages from the different URLs.

Comment: The usual VB.NET problem, surely, hundreds of questions about it already.  frmMain is a type name, not an object reference.  When you use it in a worker thread then you'll create a new object of the frmMain type.  It isn't visible, its Show() method was never called.  And can't work, the thread never called Application.Run().  Also the reason you don't get the exception you should be getting when you have a worker thread add a control.

Comment: OK, thanks for the informations. But, the problem is that the application is "stuck" because there can be up to 20 browsers. if i call navigate at the SAME time for all the webbrowser, the app is very slow and i can´t click anywhere, not even the tabpages. i tried to run some "Application.update()" in the "navigating" event of the single webbrowsers. But thats not working, so what could be the solution that the app wont getting "stuck"?